# Adding subscript formatting to all numbers in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, subscript

I'm trying to write a simple script that iterates through an input string and converts all numbers in the string to subscripted numbers.

Here is my latest attempt that iterates over an input string `item` and should create a new string containing the subscripted numbers in place of the numbers in the original string. Maybe it's not possible, but I can't seem to combine Unicode and format string literal expressions to make this work.

```py
item= 'H2O'
new=[]

sub = u'\u208'

for i,x in enumerate(item):
    if x.isdigit():
        sub=u'{x}'.format(sub)
        new.append(sub)
    else:
        new.append(x)
new=''.join(new)

new
```

I get the following error:

```py
File "<ipython-input-48-1d7d4a7394db>", line 4
    sub = u'\u208'
         ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-4: truncated \uXXXX escape
```

In the end, I'd like to do the following "conversion" to get a "number-subscripted" version (`H₂O`) of an input string (`H2O`):

```
H2O --> H₂O
```

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong or if there might be a better way to do this? 
Thanks!

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be: `u'\u2082'`

Comment: `sub = u'{x}'.format(sub)` doesn't make sense either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `str.maketrans()`.

`u'\u2080'` to `u'\u2089'` represent numbers from 0 to 9

```
sub=str.maketrans("0123456789", "₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉")
_str='C3H8O3'
_str=_str.translate(sub)
print(_str)
```

---

output

```
'C₃H₈O₃'
```

---

In your code `sub=u'\u208'` should be `sub=u'\u2082'`. Simple replace would have been enough.

```
_str='H2O'
sub=u'\u2082'
for char in _str:
    if char.isdigit():
        _str=_str.replace(char,sub)
print(_str)
```

---

```
'H₂O'
```

---

Building normal values to subscript values dictionary.

```
sub=u'\u2080'
norm_to_sub={}
for norm in '0123456789':
    norm_to_sub[norm]=sub
    sub=chr(ord(sub)+1)

print(norm_to_sub)
```

---

```
{'0': '₀', '1': '₁', '2': '₂', '3': '₃', '4': '₄', '5': '₅', '6': '₆', '7': '₇', '8': '₈', '9': '₉'}
```

As suggested by [wjandrea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4518341/wjandrea) you can do this.

```
sub = 0x2080
norm_to_sub={}
for norm in range(10):
    norm_to_sub[norm] = ord(sub + norm)
```

---

```
{'0': '₀', '1': '₁', '2': '₂', '3': '₃', '4': '₄', '5': '₅', '6': '₆', '7': '₇', '8': '₈', '9': '₉'}
```

---

You can even create a function.

```
def change_to_sub(number):
    sub=0x2080
    return ''.join(chr(sub+int(num)) for num in str(number))

print(change_to_sub(1232454353654))
```

---

```
'₁₂₃₂₄₅₄₃₅₃₆₅₄'
```

Comment: You could simplify your third method using numbers: `sub = 0x2080`, `for norm in range(10)`, `norm_to_sub[norm] = ord(sub + norm)`

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct I've realized it after you have pointed it. Thanks for taking out the time in improving the answer. Editing the answer and adding credits for the input.

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but you don't get points for edits after 2000 rep :) In any case edits by other users shouldn't fundamentally change code and I don't want to set a bad example.

Comment: You could even simplify it further with a comprehension: `norm_to_sub = {str(norm): ord(sub + norm) for norm in range(10)}`

Comment: @wjandrea I'll make sure to rollback the edits if someone hinders with the code provided by both of us. Don't worry.

Answer (score 0):

From a methodology standpoint, it's possible to reduce the operation down two two steps.  I think this also helps with readability and, if needed in the future, could let you do stuff like more easily vectorize your operation:

```py
>>> mapping = {"0": "₀", "1": "₁", "2": "₂", "3": "₃", "4": "₄", 
               "5": "₅", "6": "₆", "7": "₇", "8": "₈", "9": "₉"}
>>> formula = "CH3CH2CH2CH3"
>>> "".join([mapping.get(x) or x for x in list(formula)])
'CH₃CH₂CH₂CH₃'
```

In regards to the unicode error you're getting, I get the same error in jupyter.  But copy-pasting the characters [from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts#Superscripts_and_subscripts_block) directly into my notebook cell seems to solve the issue.

If you want to actually use the unicode codes, it looks like you're missing the last character of the code.  So `₀` should be `'\u2080'` (python3) or `u'\u2080'` (python2), `₁` is `'\u2081'`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation doesn't make sense, but your approach does. What you can do is take the integer value of the digit, add `0x2080` to get the subscript codepoint, then convert to the character.

```
import string

item = 'H2O'
sub = 0x2080
new = ''.join(chr(sub + int(c)) if c in string.digits else c for c in item)
print(new)  # -> H₂O
```

I'm using [`string.digits`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.digits) here because [`str.isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) does more than you want. It will return true for strings that cannot be converted to ints, like `'₂'` itself for example.

Comment: P.S. I'm assuming you're using Python 3 since Python 2 is EOL. This won't work in Python 2.

Comment: Thanks for the additional route and note on the use of .isdigit vs .digits, wjandrea!